# gradle - what does configure() method do

Tags: gradle

What does configure() do exactly in Gradle?

I tried to find it in Gradle official documentation but couldn't find a clear explanation.

I am looking at the `build.gradle` source code of [spring.io/sagan](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/blob/master/build.gradle).

```
def javaProjects = [ project(':sagan-site'), project(':sagan-indexer'), project(':sagan-common') ]
//...
configure(javaProjects){...}
```

What does the `configure()` method do and when to use it in general and in the context of the above `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a brief description at the end of [this section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:subproject_configuration) in the Gradle user manual. You can also find it in the [Groovy DSL Reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:configure(java.lang.Iterable,%20groovy.lang.Closure)).

In essence, it's a general way to apply configuration to a collection of projects, tasks or anything else you want to configure. The specific example you show configures a subset of the build's child projects. You can already do this for all projects or all subprojects via the `allprojects {}` and `subprojects {}` blocks:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: "java"
    version = "1.2.1"
}
```

But it may be the case that not all of your child projects are Java ones. So you replace `subprojects {}` with a `configure(...) {}` block and specify which projects you want to configure:

```
def javaProjects = ...
confgure(javaProjects) {
    apply plugin: "java"
    version = "1.2.1"
}
```

Hope that helps!